# Best way: Facebook JSON Parse to MongoDB (Python3)

Tags: python, json, mongodb, facebook

I'm trying to find out the best way to parse Facebook JSON responses to MongoDB.

FB Event JSON:

```
{
  "description": "Event description",
  "name": "Event name",
  "place": {
    "name": "Place name",
    "location": {
      "city": "City",
      "country": "Country",
      "latitude": -26.31604,
      "longitude": -48.83667,
      "state": "State",
      "street": "Street address",
      "zip": "000000"
    },
    "id": "429579150543987"
  },
  "start_time": "2017-10-27T19:00:00-0200",
  "id": "1557095844358825"
}
```

Sometimes an event doesn't have all those fields above, i.e.: `location` and `place` are optional.

So I did:

```
event_dict = {
    'id': event['id'],
    'name': event['name'],
    'start_time': event['start_time']
}

if ("place" in event):
    if ("name" in event['place']):
        event_dict['place'] = event['place']['name']
    if ("location" in event['place']):
        if ("street" in event['place']['location']):
            event_dict['street'] = event['place']['location']['street']
        if ("zip" in event['place']['location']):
            event_dict['zip'] = event['place']['location']['zip']
        if ("city" in event['place']['location']):
            event_dict['city'] = event['place']['location']['city']
        if ("state" in event['place']['location']):
            event_dict['state'] = event['place']['location']['state']
        if ("country" in event['place']['location']):
            event_dict['country'] = event['place']['location']['country']

if ("end_time" in event):
    event_dict['end_time'] = event['end_time']

if ("description" in event):
    event_dict['description'] = event['description']

event_list.append(event_dict)
```

`event_list` is the list of dicts that I'm saving on MongoDB.

My main question is: **is there a better way to do it instead of a lot if-then-else conditions?**

Comment: So you want a one-level dict as the output, with any key-value pairs in that dict?

Comment: @chasmani Yes but some fields from the original JSON are optional. My code is working, but I don't think it's the better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace most of your if statements with `key: event.get("key", None)` or for nested attributes `val: event.get('key1', None).get('key2', None)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a json object to a dict, then just do:

```
import json

event_dict = json.loads(event)
```

Comment: Hey, buddy. Thanks. Buuut my problem is that I need to change the original structure to import to MongoDB. As you can see in my example, the original JSON returns a multidimensional attributes for `place` and I need to restructure to one-level dictionary (and some fields are optionals).

Answer (score 1):

To convert everything to a one level dictionary, you can use a recursive function to go through the dictionary, and extract key-value pairs as they come up. Something like this:

```
event = {
  "description": "Event description",
  "name": "Event name",
  "place": {
    "name": "Place name",
    "location": {
      "city": "City",
      "country": "Country",
      "latitude": -26.31604,
      "longitude": -48.83667,
      "state": "State",
      "street": "Street address",
      "zip": "000000"
    },
    "id": "429579150543987"
  },
  "start_time": "2017-10-27T19:00:00-0200",
  "id": "1557095844358825"
}


one_level_dict = {}

def recursive_extraction(dict, base_string = ""):
    for key, value in dict.items():
        if type(value) is type({}):
            recursive_extraction(value, base_string + key + "_")
        else:
            one_level_dict[base_string + key] = value

recursive_extraction(event)
print(one_level_dict)
```

This is a bit scrappy, but you should be able to modify it to your purposes.

(this is for python3, for python2 I think you will need to replace dict.items() with dict.iteritems())

EDIT : Added a base_string to maintain the context of the json structure for values at lower levels.

Comment: I think it's kinda dangerous if I get two keys with same name in different levels. Right? But thanks anyways!

Comment: @izn I fixed it a bit based on your comment, now you will get keys out like "place_id" and "place_location_city"